# Changing image with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using jquery mobile to make an app. I'm playing a sound file when the page loads and displaying an image to turn the sound file off when clicked. everything is working fine however I can only get the image to change on the index page. I can turn off the sound file on any page however the image wont change on any other page. please help =) <3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newsrc = "soundOff.png";

function changeImage() {
    var sample = document.getElementById("foobar");
    sample.pause();

    if ( newsrc == "soundOff.png" ) {
        document.images["sound"].src = "/img/soundOff.png";
        document.images["sound"].alt = "Sound Off";
        newsrc  = "soundOn.png";
    }
    else {
        var sample = document.getElementById("foobar");
        sample.play();
        document.images["sound"].src = "/img/soundOn.png";
        document.images["sound"].alt = "Sound On";
        newsrc  = "soundOff.png";
    }
}
var sample = document.getElementById("foobar");
sample.play();
```

Comment: Could you post the file structure that you have, because that might be the issue if the paths are not correct.

Comment: This question IS NOT about jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.images["sound"].src = "/img/soundOff.png";
```

Should be this:

```
document.getElementById('your_id').src = "/img/soundOff.png";
```

Your path seems a little wierd to me.Check it properly

Comment: Everything works fine apart from the image will only change on the index page. It would change on anyother page :/

Comment: Yes you are right, it is the path however I am unsure what to change it too. Shouldn't the / take it to the root folder? Working on wamp.

Comment: myproject->images->profilepic.jpg...assume i have a folder like this.This is how i give the path considering your file is outside images.

`images/propic.jpg`